# Default Device assistance app Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-7.0-nougat, android-settings, google-voice

Sadly, now we can no more map our apps to Long press home button Event. But, There is a settings page where it is possible to change the default device assistance app:
[Default Device Assistance app on Samsung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d89pa.png)

Is it anyway possible to change the default device assistance app programmatically or even launch the settings page (via intent) to make the user change the setting?

Comment: this is what i want dude, are you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it anyway possible to change the default device assistance app programmatically

Fortunately, no, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

> even launch the settings page (via intent) to make the user change the setting?

Ideally, there would be [an action in `Settings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) for this, but I do not see one that looks like it is specific to the assistant.