# How to receive Assistant Intent in Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, assistant

Is there a way to "answer" with a Flutter App when a user long-pressed the home button (like Google Assistant, Alexa and other minor assistants do)?

I thought it may be an *intent* to receive (something similar to receiving the *sharing intent*, allowing users to share a photo in your app) but I couldn't find anything about it... Any idea?

Comment: Unclear if you are looking for [Default Device assistance app Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44171434/295004) or something related to [Google Assistant  App Actions built-in intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents)

Comment: I would like my app to be available as Default Device assistance app, and then do something when users long-press the home button